# How to create a complex object in ESQL

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I would like to create the following JSON object in ESQL and put it on the SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data. How do I do that?

```
{ 
      "active"   : [ {"name" : "test"}, 
                     {"name": "test2"}]
      "inactive" : [ {"name" : "test3"}]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard procedure for IIB developers who want to output a specific format of XML/JSON:

1. Use a text editor to create the document that you want to output
2. Create a simple message flow that parses that document.

   - On the FileInput node (or HTTPInput, if you prefer) set the Domain to 'JSON'
   - Make sure that the second node is a Trace node with Pattern set to '${Root}'.
3. Put the example JSON through the message flow
4. Examine the Trace node output, *paying special attention to the field type on each node*
5. Write ESQL that produces an identical message tree under OutputRoot.JSON.Data

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet demonstrates how to create JSON you need:

```
    CREATE FUNCTION Main() RETURNS BOOLEAN
    BEGIN
        -- Create JSON domain
        CREATE LASTCHILD OF OutputRoot DOMAIN 'JSON' NAME 'JSON';
        -- Create root Data field
        CREATE FIELD OutputRoot.JSON.Data;
        DECLARE OutMsg REFERENCE TO OutputRoot.JSON.Data;

        CREATE FIELD OutMsg.active IDENTITY (JSON.Array)active;
        SET OutMsg.active.Item[1].name = 'test';
        SET OutMsg.active.Item[2].name = 'test2';
        SET OutMsg.(JSON.Array)inactive.Item[1].name = 'test3';
        RETURN TRUE;
    END;
```

Also you can read more information about work with JSON here [Manipulating messages in the JSON domain](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/bc28410_.html) and here [Creating or transforming a JSON message by using a message map](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_10.0.0/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/sm12035_.html)